# javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jboss7.x

Hi i am using Spring 3 application on Jboss 7.1 final and i have mysql community server database created, and i added the datasource in **standalone.xml** file as follows:

```
<datasources>

                <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/myapp" pool-name="myapp_pool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myapp</connection-url>
                    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>root</user-name>
                        <password>root</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>

                    <driver name="com.mysql.jdbc" module="com.mysql.jdbc">
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
```

but i am getting following exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve transation read-only status server

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'tx_read_only'

[org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000319: Could not get database metadata: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/myapp

Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/myapp

Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000658: Unexpected throwable while trying to create a connection: null

Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve transation read-only status server

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'tx_read_only'


15:19:21,063 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000299: Could not complete schema update: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/myapp

Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/myapp

Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000658: Unexpected throwable while trying to create a connection: null

Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve transation read-only status server

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'tx_read_only'


15:19:21,997 INFO  [org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain] (MSC service thread 1-4) Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@152c70f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@18aae91, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@1cabeb0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@1ad45f1, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@cb0e99, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@12b676c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@92e514, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1fd8fa0, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1e05472, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@c82e42]
15:19:22,019 INFO  [org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator] (MSC service thread 1-4) Checking whether login URL '/' is accessible with your configuration
15:19:22,040 WARN  [org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator] (MSC service thread 1-4) Anonymous access to the login page doesn't appear to be enabled. This is almost certainly an error. Please check your configuration allows unauthenticated access to the configured login page. (Simulated access was rejected: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied)
15:19:22,304 INFO  [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (MSC service thread 1-4) Using JTA UserTransaction: org.jboss.tm.usertx.client.ServerVMClientUserTransaction@252981
15:19:22,306 INFO  [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (MSC service thread 1-4) Using JTA TransactionManager: com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerDelegate@16ce36
15:19:22,307 INFO  [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (MSC service thread 1-4) Using JTA TransactionSynchronizationRegistry: com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionSynchronizationRegistryImple@13c50d0
15:19:22,314 INFO  [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (MSC service thread 1-4) Using JTA UserTransaction: org.jboss.tm.usertx.client.ServerVMClientUserTransaction@252981
15:19:22,316 INFO  [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (MSC service thread 1-4) Using JTA TransactionManager: com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerDelegate@16ce36
15:19:22,317 INFO  [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (MSC service thread 1-4) Using JTA TransactionSynchronizationRegistry: com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionSynchronizationRegistryImple@13c50d0
15:19:22,338 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-4) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6170 ms
15:19:22,442 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-4) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401) for context '/myapp'
15:19:25,434 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (MSC service thread 1-4) Running on PrimeFaces 4.0-SNAPSHOT
15:19:25,435 INFO  [org.omnifaces.eventlistener.VersionLoggerEventListener] (MSC service thread 1-4) Using OmniFaces version 1.5-SNAPSHOT-20130422
15:19:25,440 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-4) Monitoring jndi:/default-host/myapp/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
15:19:25,488 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /myapp
15:19:25,497 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
15:19:25,498 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 19299ms - Started 435 of 513 services (76 services are passive or on-demand)
15:19:25,685 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "myapp.war"
```

i removed the lines after the exception because the post limit.
please advise about this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having two different installation for MySQL database, uninstalled them and installed latest version of MySQL community server and issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Should be the driver package version of the MySQL database and you use the database problems. you can try another driver package versions